# Javascript mongoDB takes variable name rather than value of the variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous

I am using mongoDB with javascript. I am updating an item in a collection using the following function and passing in "server_name" as the variable attribute_name:

```
    async update_server_attribute(db, server_id, attribute_name, new_value){
        var my_query = { "server_id": server_id }
        var updated_val = { $set: {attribute_name: new_value } }
        db.collection("servers").updateOne(my_query, updated_val)
    },
```

I would expect the dict to update to the following:

```
{"server_name" : new_val}
```

Instead it does the following:

```
{"server_name" : old_value, "attribute_name" : new_val}
```

Can anyone explain this strange behavior and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, `{attribute_name: new_value }` is treated the same as `{"attribute_name": new_value }`. To have JavaScript use the *value* of `attribute_name` as the key, use [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) syntax by surrounding it with square brackets:

```
var updated_val = { $set: {[attribute_name]: new_value } }
```

Comment: This fixes the issue perfectly and explains what was wrong. Thanks!